# Error connecting Database in dotnetnuke v7.4.0 after upgrading

Tags: iis-7, dotnetnuke

```
<ConnectionStrings>
<add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=DNN-CLONE-STAGE\SQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=latitudecg_dnn;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</ConnectionStrings>

<appSettings>
<add key="SiteSqlServer" value="Data Source=DNN-CLONE-STAGE\SQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=latitudecg_dnn;Integrated Security=True" />
</appSettings>
```

This is my code to connect DB and dotnetnuke site(v7.4.0). I used this same connection when I upgraded from v6 to v7. But after upgradation, it shows me error **Dotnetnuke Error ...Database Connection failed..** I don't know whats the error. I am running my site from IIS localhost like C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitename ..

Can anyone tell me the solution?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Check `EventLog` table and post Error Message here. It should be the XML string.

Comment: There are many such errors in that table.. But I found the error that adding my localhost to portalAlias table... Am accessing my site using http://localhost/sitename .. how am I supposed to add this entry to portal as well as PortalAlias table...

Comment: Your actual error is the last record of `EventLog` table. Your HTTPAlias should be `localhost/sitename`.